# Why does "Der Ball ist rund" mean "Alles ist möglich"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase

I know that the whole quote is

> Der Ball ist rund und das Spiel dauert 90 Minuten

by Sepp Herberger.

I got it from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepp_Herberger) in English only that it means something, and from [this page](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/like-chess-only-without-the-dice-german-football-s-greatest-sayings-a-558638-2.html) that it must be something inspiring. And I have also checked the [Wikipedia in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepp_Herberger) but I find it is a tall order for me to understand all what is explained.

I come to here to seek an answer by taking a short cut(I know if I have the knowledge of the related history it would be not hard).

Comment: According to the german Wikipedia-article, these are two independently quotes: "Der Ball ist rund." and "Ein Spiel dauert 90 Minuten."

Comment: A round ball can easily go any way you imagine. A hockey puck can move only horizontally, and a cube cannot easily move at all.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Are you sure that, assuming the same surface properties as the puck, a cube would move considerably less easily than the hockey puck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statements by Sepp Herberger were nothing more than stating the obvious: of course the ball is round, and everyone knows that a (normal) soccer game lasts 90 minutes.

There is no story or deeper sense behind that two sentences, just Sepp liking to give interviews and forming humorous statements.

People tried to put sense in these statements later that was not originally in there.

Both statements (**der Ball ist rund** and **das Spiel dauert 90 Minuten**) do not belong together and were made in different interviews on different dates.

They became a *complete* statement later as these were the most striking ones made by Sepp Herberger.

The meanings that were later added to the sayings are:

**Der Ball ist rund**
The ball can go in any direction, it is not predictable what happens in a soccer game
  --> **everything can happen**

**Das Spiel dauert 90 Minuten**
In soccer one team can dominate a complete match but does not score even one goal. 
Sometimes it happens, that the *underdog* then in the very last minute of a match gets one single chance and scores, and then wins the game.
Trainers then often use this statement, to say: it is not enough to play good 89 minutes, as every game lasts 90 minutes and the result can be changed within the last second.

Comment: Der Sinn des zweiten Teils, der von Dir richtig als unzusammenhängend identifiziert wird, war gar nicht gefragt. Abseits ist, wenn der Schiedsrichter pfeift. (Oder war es Tor/Elfmeter/Foul?)

Comment: Das ist sinnvoll! Danke schön!

Answer (score 7):

It means: We don't have any other facts than these - everything else would be guessing. Anything is possible and there's nothing definitive I can say.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody seems to be mentioning the massive cultural wellspring that this quote spread through society, the movie "Lola Rennt" (Run Lola Run).

https://www.theguardian.com/football/worldcup2006blog/2006/jul/03/theballisroundandkeepson

In the German film Run, Lola, Run there's a scene before the title sequence in which an odd-looking referee throws the ball up in the air. The camera focuses on the ball as it spins in the air, and a narrator says something along the lines of "The ball is round. The game lasts 90 minutes. That's fact. Everything else is theory."

The accepted answer appears to state that Sepp Herberger did not state these two statements together. If that is so, then someone else did, and then someone else quoted that someone else in the opening scene of the credits.

The phrase became very much circulated both in its original German and into English, where  "the ball is round, the game lasts 90 minutes, that's fact, everything else is theory", was widely introduced into the English speaking world as a thought, or quotable quote, and people like myself who speak both some German and English also went back and discovered the original quote and its pre-movie origins, but I wish to point out that people who have no idea about the quotes author would have heard it in German or English through the film.

Comment: Hier geht es aber um die deutsche Sprache. Von Herberger sind noch mehr Zitate im Umlauf, etwa "Abseits ist, wenn der Schiedsrichter pfeift". Oft reagiert man auf ein Herbergerzitat mit einem zweiten, in größerer Runde kommt es dann aber leicht zu einer ganzen Kette.

Comment: Hier geht es aber um die deutsche Sprache.

"But this is about the German language."

It is about the question the original poster asked, in halting contact English, about a German phrase.
Agreed. 

The movie I mention has a soundtrack with actors in german.

The original poster knows the originator of the quote is Von Herberger. Which is true.

But the quote gained a second life as the very famous opening of a German movie.  

In American Culture, Von Herberger would be compared to Yogi Berra.  Eminently quotable.

I particular love this film and wish to remind folks of it.

Comment: Not exactly. First, it is just Herberger, not Von Herberger which, btw., if it would be written, would be "von Herberger", like "von Neumann". Second, it isn't second life, but 172th live, its quoted quite often. And your answer is not answering the "Why", which is the topic of the question. Extravagant knowledge which is loosely associated with the question doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: The question is literally asking why does A mean B.  This is a cultural phenomenon at its heart. Sorry you are so hostile to people shedding light on culture.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't agree to two of your premises: A) I'm not hostile to people. I only discuss statements, answers, ideas, not people. Don't take anything personally. B) The film "Lola rennt" isn't an independend source. To understand the phrase in the film, you need to know already what it's source is. It's just a loop way.

Comment: As the quote says, the facts are clear, the rest (including your opinions and mine) are theory.

Comment: @userunknown: "To understand the phrase in the film, you need to know already what it's source is." - if the phrase is presented as described here, i.e. in a statement like "The ball is round. The game lasts 90 minutes. That's fact. Everything else is theory." that kind of contains its own explanation, why do you need to know what the source is? Frankly, being not interested in sports, I do not even *know* the (apparently quite well-known to soccer fans) person named Sepp Herberger, and yet the movie quotation instantly makes sense to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Welche Bedeutung von "Der Ball ist rund" kannst Du aus der Filmszene entnehmen, ohne den Bezug zu Herbergerinterviews zu kennen? Was wird damit ausgedrückt? Das Fakten Fakten sind und der Ball rund, nicht eckig? Oder dass der Ball, weil er rund ist, leicht die Richtung ändern kann und schlecht vorhersehbar ist? *Lola rennt* sahen 2 Mio. Zuschauer, rat mal wie viele die Herbergersprüche gehört haben? Wahrscheinlich mehr als 10x so viele.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn sich die Filmszene wie hier beschrieben abspielt, das heißt 'a narrator says something along the lines of "The ball is round. The game lasts 90 minutes. That's fact. Everything else is theory."', dann kann ich daraus die Aussage entnehmen, dass bis auf einige grundlegende Fakten alles offen ist. Das genügt doch schon, um den Satz als Umschreibung für "Alles ist möglich." in Erinnerung zu behalten. Wozu muss ich da wissen, wer dieser Sepp Herberger ist oder ob er vielleicht Ähnliches in etwas anderer Zusammenstellung schon mal früher gesagt hat?

Comment: Ein Ignorant muss gar nichts wissen. Diese Darstellung zu einem Film, der dieses weitverbreitete Zitat aufgreift, beantwortet die Frage nicht und sollte zu einem Kommentar eingedampft werden. Die Floskel ist nicht vom Film, sondern von Herberger geschaffen worden, und der Film hat ihr keine neue Bedeutung verliehen - man muss also, um die Frage zu beantworten, zur Quelle.

Answer (score 3):

It's a saying that although the odds may be heavily in favour of 1 team, a round ball can travel in any direction & thus the underdog (unfavoured team) still has the possibility of winning the game.

The phrase is often used when there is perceived talent mismatch between 2 teams. Since the next 90 minutes are yet unknown, the possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this very much sounds like a blunt tautology, people have interpreted a lot into this saying: Apparently, it's more important what's not said about football than what's said:

It basically means "Those two are the immutable facts - Everything else is up to the teams and everything else is possible."

Comment: Since, as already noted in an answer and a comment, both statements where made independently from another, your analyse is false.

Comment: "user unknown" sure has a strong opinion

Answer (score -1):

The ball has no favorites. It doesn't care if the national champion is heavily favored by bookmakers against an underdog village team. It's indifferent to one's reputation, which has to be proven on the field.

Answer (score -3):

**»Der Ball ist rund**« reminds me of the Cole Porter musical

> [Anything Goes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anything_Goes)

while **»Ein Spiel dauert 90 Minuten«** guides me to the phrase

> it’s not over till it’s over

Comment: Der zweite Satz war nicht gefragt. Deine Assoziationen auch nicht.